# Is it possible to use Keras module in Pytorch script?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm creating a network similar to [lpcnet](https://github.com/mozilla/LPCNet) introduced by mozilla but in PyTorch. At the one point I need the module src/mdense.py in my script but it is written with keras. Is it possible to import keras module to torch framework? What could be the easiest way? I don't want to re-write the module with PyTorch.

There exists some converters but as I see, these are in early stages. Is there any I can depend on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not really, you can import it (as in python `import`), but Keras code won't work with PyTorch as they use different differentiation methods and they are completely different libraries. The only way is to rewrite the module using PyTorch's API.